# Ethereum alternative to bitcoind

Tags: bitcoind, ethereum

A client have payment system that uses `bitcoind` wallet / daemon.

I know he can expand to litecoin / dogecoin by just copy litecoind / dogecoind then console commands are almost the same.

I am wondering if same possibility exists for Etherium?

What software I need in order to replace `bitcoind`? I googled already, but I can not find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ethereum nodes are [geth](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/) and [parity](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-ethereum/).

Unlike Litecoin and Dogecoin, Ethereum is not a derivative of Bitcoin. Thus, the RPC interface is completely different, and you will not be able to simply point an existing  Bitcoin based system at the ethereum node. You will likely need to rewrite whatever you require to work with Ethereum APIs.

Comment: That was extremely helpful!